# Maximum size for query collection parameter in JPA 2.1 / Hibernate 5.2.17

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

Is there a maximum size for a query collection parameter in JPA 2.1 / Hibernate 5.2.17 (connecting to PostgreSQL using JDBC driver, if that matters)?

e.g., what is the maximum allowable and/or recommended size for ids in the following code, to avoid any possible bugs or issues in JPA / Hibernate / PostreSQL?:

```
@Query("select ee from ExampleEntity ee where ee.exampleId in :ids")
fun findAllIn(ids: Collection<Long>): Collection<ExampleEntity>
```

Comment: I think the JDBC driver has a limit of 32000 parameters (or something along those lines)

Comment: We had an error with more than 1000 parameters.

Comment: @SvenM. did you encounter this error with PostgreSQL? or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @naXa Sorry, I can only confirm this Oracle. But I meant the error message came from Spring. I thought the problem was that he can't build a statement with more than 1000 parameters. But I'm not quite sure.